# After re-install, "node" command looks in the wrong directory

Tags: node.js

On ubuntu 16.04, I upgraded node.js to version 10.16.0.  The new version is installed and working; however, typing 'node' on the shell command line looks in the wrong place:

```
# node -v
bash: /usr/local/bin/node: No such file or directory
```

The newly installed version is in /usr/bin:

```
# which node
/usr/bin/node

# /usr/bin/node -v
v10.16.0

# echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin
```

Where is the 'node' command being defined?  Why is it not using $PATH to find the new version at /usr/bin?

Answer (score 1):

oops, my bad.  I was still running the same shell.  When I closed it out and logged back in, the path was set correctly.